# Provider hosted app - how to get FedAuth and rtfa cookie of the current logged-in user

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-clientobject, office365-restapi, sharepoint-webservice

I am using Provider-Hosted App for Office 365. I want to get version collection of list item, for that just tried to access using list.asmx service. To call this SP service, have to pass cookie(FedAuth and rtFa). but i have only accesstoken with me, is any way to get cookie of the current logged in user?

What I have tried:

I have tried to call list.asmx service using HttpWebRequest with access token, it throws 401 exception. it ask for either cookie or credentials. (user already logged in the SharePoint site in browser, so i could not ask user to give credentials for this). so my better option to go with cookie.